# Building .NET Standard Library from Jenkins using MSBuild

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, .net-standard

Building [MazeCreator](https://github.com/codefoco/MazeCreator) solution  with some .NETStandand libraries throws a [thousands](https://gist.github.com/viniciusjarina/3a7f50f5df102576050299274420243f) of errors when building from jenkins, complaining about the BCL types:

```
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Enum' is not defined or imported
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
```

All the environment variables set by `VsDevCmd.bat` were properly set on Jenkins.

The build is calling:

```
nuget restore
msbuild MazeCreator.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

Which works fine from `Developer Command Prompt for VS`

Building from the command line works fine, the build is  also green on [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/viniciusjarina/mazecreator), [Linux](https://travis-ci.org/codefoco/MazeCreator) and Mac.

Comment: Wrong version of msbuild, probably.  That seems to never not be a problem with Jenkins.  Use the full path name.

Comment: No joy. Even using the full path of nuget.exe and MSBuild.exe :(

Comment: That's another odd thing about [jenkins] questions, they never tell what exact path they used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was related with the Jekins Service permissions.

After change how `Jenkin Service` log in ([MSBuild - Jenkins - Nuget integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523964/msbuild-jenkins-nuget-integration?rq=1))

The nuget can restore the .NETStandard dependencies properly and the build now is green.

Comment: How did you changed the `Jenkin Service` permissions? I'm having the same problem here.

Comment: There is a `Log On` tab on your service property, also you will need to call `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` to set VS environment variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

We had NuGet.exe checked into our SVN source tree at version **3.4.4-rtm-1321**.

Then we updated it to NuGet.exe **4.7.1** using this command and then our builds started to work on Jenkins again:

```
NuGet.exe update -self
```

As an aside, we don't run **Jenkins** as a service, we run it as a user process so we can some **DirectX** unit testing which can't be done in Session 0.